# How to make parts of a code wait until another part has completed using async-await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I need to have a part of a function call be completed first and then the rest of it to resume.  The goal is that I need to register/record how long the first part of the process runs for reporting purposes.

In the code below, the first `var data` run using input parameters `X2,Y2,Z2` to find corresponding values in a database. `var api` is triggered automatically and records a start time.

I then need `var data` to complete and then run `var api2` which will register a completion time. This will give me the approximate run time for “var data” within acceptable levels of accuracy.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

```
function Searh_09() {
   var data = {
     'X': document.id('X2').value,
     'Y': document.id('Y2').value,
     'Z': document.id('Z2').value,
     'Transform': 'Templates/Report/Standard.xslt'
   }; 

   if (!X)
      return;

   if (!Y)
      return;

   if (!Z)
       return;

   var api = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
   api.invokeJson('StartTime',data);

   var api2 = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
   api2.invokeJson('EndTime');
}
```

Comment: What is `qbo3.ProcessObject`?  What does the `invokeJson()` method do?  If it's asynchronous, does it return a Promise or accept a callback?

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @David qbo3.ProcessObject is declaring StartTime and EndTime as objects in a web application (QBO) for use internally. The invokeJson is used to enable the use of Json in translating data across a server... This is my best understanding, the web application QBO has been recently implemented and combines a lot of high level coding "beneath the hood" that I'm not able to access.

Comment: @T8100: You're going to need to know the specifics about how these objects/methods perform their asynchronous operations.  In general such a method would either accept a callback or return a Promise.  With that information you can structure your code to await that operation before performing the next operation.

Comment: @KooiInc I'm sorry but above is the best I can do..."qbo3.ProcessObject is declaring StartTime and EndTime as objects in a web application (QBO) for use internally. The invokeJson is used to enable the use of Json in translating data across a server..."

Comment: @David here's an explanation of the QBO stuff, I'm still not getting it though, any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994800/qbo3-javascript-promises/66994801#66994801

Comment: @KooiInc here's an explanation of the QBO stuff, I'm still not getting it though, any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994800/qbo3-javascript-promises/66994801#66994801

Comment: @T8100: That doesn't go into much detail, but from the syntax used on the answer it appears that `invokeJson()` accepts a third parameter which is an object containing a variety of properties, two of which are `success` and `error` callback functions which would be invoked at a later time depending on the completion of failure of the `invokeJson` operation.  Anything you want to happen after the operation completes would need to go in those functions.  (Or for a more elegant Promise-based approach, that answer shows how to wrap `invokeJson` in a Promise.)

Answer (score 0):

[A link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994800/qbo3-javascript-promises/66994801#66994801) in comments offers *some* insight into this `invokeJson` operation.  Specifically this bit here:

```
invokeJson(method, data, { success: resolve, error: reject })
```

Those `success` and `error` properties on that third method parameter are callbacks.  Similar to the often seen jQuery AJAX implementation, they essentially are where you would create functions that will be invoked at a later time when the operation finishes (or fails).

Since your code is invoking 2 of these operations, you effectively have three "moments" you can debug.  Before the first operation, between the two operations, and after the second operation.  Using the tools you have that might look something like this:

```
console.log('Before first operation.');
var api = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
api.invokeJson('StartTime', data, {
  success: function () {
    console.log('Between the operations.');
    var api2 = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
    api2.invokeJson('EndTime', null, {
      success: function () {
        console.log('After second operation.');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

As you can see, each call to `invokeJson()` includes a third parameter with a `success` callback function, which will be invoked after the asynchronous operation completes.

---

Now, to your question, specifically:

> How to make parts of a code wait until another part has completed **using async-await**

The library you're using doesn't seem to make use of async/await.  However, [the answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994800/qbo3-javascript-promises/66994801#66994801) in comments shows how to get around that.  You'd wrap the operation in a `Promise`, the structure of which includes `resolve` and `reject` functions which do *exactly* what the `success` and `error` callbacks do.

Slightly modifying the code in that answer, you can create a function which accepts one of your `api` objects and returns a promise around `invokeJson`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
async function invokeJsonAsync(api, str, data) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    api.invokeJson(str, data, { success: resolve, error: reject });
  });
}
```

Now instead of calling `invokeJson` directly on your `api` objects, you'd pass them to this function and `await` the returned `Promise`:

```
var api = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
await invokeJsonAsync(api, 'StartTime', data);

var api2 = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
await invokeJsonAsync(api2, 'EndTime');
```

Note that you'd also need to use the `async` keyword on your `Searh_09` function definition in order to use `await` within that function.

The linked answer takes it a step further by making this function part of the `api` objects themselves.  Which would be cleaner if you expect to use this a lot.  The programmer appears to have done that with the intent of using `.then()` to chain these calls together.  Using `await` has the same effect, and is specifically what you were asking for.

---

Overall, it's worth understanding that this isn't "making parts of the code wait until other parts complete".  Code does that by default.  It imperatively executes line by line until it completes.

However, *some* of the operations invoked by code these days are *asynchronous*.  Which means the context of performing that operation is offloaded to another process *outside* of the code that's running.  The code that's running will continue to execute more statements.  At a later time, when that asynchronous process completes, it will transfer control back to this code for any potential follow-up.

Since JavaScript is single-threaded, any follow-ups to these asynchronous operations will happen after all of the imperative code statements have been executed.  The follow-up operations which later get invoked are these callback functions.  (Hence the name... It's a function that will be invoked when the control is returned to the code.  The other process is using this function to "call us back".)

`async` and `await` simply wrap this in cleaner syntax.  But ultimately what's being "awaited" is a `Promise` which has callback functions.  When you use `await` you're basically telling the code that everything after this statement in the current function is the callback.