# qbo3 Javascript promises

Tags: promise, qbo3

How do I chain qbo3 API calls **as promises** in Javascript?

I’m trying to get the JavaScript below to pause after hitting `var api` until `var data` has been completed.  Then after being completed, the function can continue on as usual.  The overall goal being to get an approx. measure of how long it is taking for the query to run after being called on through the function call.

```js
var data = {...};
var api1 = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
api1.invokeJson('StartRecordingTime',data);                                             

var api2 = new qbo3.ProcessObject({target: 'row_4'});
api2.invokeHtml('RealWorldApiCall', data);

var api3 = new qbo3.ProcessObject();
api3.invokeJson('EndRecordingTime');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a promise based on a qbo3 API call as follows:

```js
qbo3.getPromise = function(cn, method, data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    new (qbo3[cn] || qbo3[cn + 'Object'])().invokeJson(method, data, { success: resolve, error: reject });
  })
}
```

where:

- `cn`: is the className of the API endpoint (e.g. `Process`, `Loan`, `Person`, `Message`, etc.)
- `method`: is the class method to be invoked (e.g. `Select`, `Search`, `Update`, etc.)
- `data`: is the `JSON` data to be submitted

> The `(qbo3[cn] || qbo3[cn + 'Object'])` expression is just a bit of sugar to allow you to pass either `Process` or `ProcessObject` as the `cn` parameter to `qbo3.getPromise(...)`.

Then you can use:

```js
var data = {...}
var myPromise = qbo3.getPromise('Process', 'StartRecordingTime', data)
  .then(return qbo3.getPromise('Process', 'RealWorldApiCall', data))
  .then(return qbo3.getPromise('Process', 'EndRecordingTime', {}))
```

More generic usage leveraging the results of one API for the data being passed to a subsequent call:

```js
var somePromise = qbo3.getPromise('Person', 'Search', {"Person": "someuser@acme.com"})
  .then(json => {
    const id = json.PersonCollection.PersonItem[0].PersonID;
    return qbo3.getPromise('ProcessObject', 'Search', { "CreatedPersonID": id })
  }).then(processes => console.log(processes));
```

---

Note that if you're just troubleshooting response times, `qbo3` includes an `X-Execution-Time` response header all API calls. This header is not passed to the `resolve` method, you can inspect it from Chrome's developer console's `Network` table, pictured here:

[image]